# Docker: not found when running cmds in jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am new to docker and CI. I am trying to create a jenkinsfile that would build and test my application, then build a docker image with the Dockerfile i've composed and then push it into AWS ECR. The steps I am stuck on is building an image with docker, i receive and error message `docker: not found`. I downloaded docker plug-in and configured it in the global tool configuration tab. Am i not adding it into tools correctly?

There was another post wear you could use kubernetes to do that however kubernetes no longer supports docker.

image of how i configured docker in global tools config:
[global tool config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmOl3.png)

error

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/client-pipeline_feature-jenkins@tmp/durable-41220eb0/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/client-pipeline_feature-jenkins@tmp/durable-41220eb0/script.sh: docker: not found
```

[error with permission to sock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcJLW.png)

```
def gv
containerVersion = "1.0"
appName = "foodcore"
imageName = appName + ":" + version
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        CI = 'true'
    }
    tools {
      nodejs "node"
      docker "docker"
    }
    stages {
        stage("init") {
            steps {
                script {
                   gv = load "script.groovy"
                   CODE_CHANGES = gv.getGitChanges()
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build frontend") {
            steps {
                dir("client") {
                    sh 'npm install'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build backend") {
            steps {
                dir("server") {
                    sh 'npm install'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("test") {
            when {
                expression {
                    script {
                        CODE_CHANGES == false
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                dir("client") {
                    sh 'npm test'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build docker image") {
            when {
                expression {
                    script {
                       env.BRANCH_NAME.toString().equals('Main') && CODE_CHANGES == false
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh "docker build -t ${imageName} ."
            }
        }
        stage("push docker image") {
            when {
                expression {
                    env.BRANCH_NAME.toString().equals('Main')
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin repoURI'
                sh 'docker tag foodcore:latest ...repoURI
                sh 'docker push repoURI'
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use echo hello world to make...

Comment: this is the error i receive after that line of code ```Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?```

Comment: its running as a docker container                                                          
```CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS         PORTS                                              NAMES
9279f6d86bfd   jenkins/jenkins:lts   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   5 days ago   Up 8 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   gallant_ellis```

Comment: Run the Jenkins docker container with -v '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' argument

Comment: so i gave it a try and it definitely works. The error i recieve now is ``` dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied```

i tried sudo usermod -a-G docker $USER but usermod couldnt be found in my OS

Comment: i did that, is something suppose to happen?

Comment: i gave it a try and it still denied me, i posted an image link of my error
steps i took: sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock...then..docker run -v '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts

Comment: this is the output: srwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan  9 06:09 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: doing that inside jenkins i get a ```chown: changing ownership of '/var/run/docker.sock': Operation not permitted```

Answer (score 0):

Docker should be installed on the server Jenkins is running. The docker plugin provided by Jenkins is just like a tool to generate some snippets for the pipeline scripts. Installing and configuring the tool doesn't install a docker daemon. Please check if docker is installed on the OS or not.

Comment: i checked with ```docker -v``` to see the version of docker installed and it gives me back a version. So i definitely have docker in my OS.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in the thread, you are start getting permission denied on docker.sock.

docker.sock permissions will be lost if you restart system or docker service.

To make it persistence setup a cron to change ownership after each reboot

```
@reboot chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

and When you restart the docker, make sure to run the below command

```
chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Or you can put a cron for it also, which will execute in each every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To use docker inside Jenkins build, There are 2 methods.

1. Use Jenkins docker plugins as describe in above solution.
2. Or install docker itself in the Jenkins container and mount the docker.sock file.